# babel without transpiling async await (no polyfill)

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, transpiler

This is the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`
Every question I've found suggest to install a polyfill which will increase the bundle size.
Since I'm targeting latest Chrome, I want to use async/await **as is**. No polyfill. How to explain that to babel?

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 2 versions",
            "Chrome >= 59"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

using chrome > 59 did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is

```
"last 2 versions"
```

which tells Babel to transpile (amongst others) for **IE 10**.

Comment: Thanks, works. Didn't consider IE10. Is there another way to tell babel not to transpile specific features? Instead of specifying browsers